# Why can't I change the maximum processor state in my laptop?

Tags: laptop, cpu

[image]

When I try to change the 100% of maximum processor state a lower percentage, it does not change. When I put any number it will return autumatically to 100%, even if I press apply. E.g. from 70 it will return to 100.

I did that because there is a problem with the fan in my laptop – it sounds loud without doing anything and when I want to play video games it sounds even louder, and my laptop starts getting very hot.

I bought my laptop two weeks ago, so it's still new and it has good specifications (Windows 10, Intel Core i7, 2TB hard drive, a Dell Inspiron 15 5000 Series).

Comment: Your laptop shouldn't be having these problems. You should get it serviced by the manufacturer under warranty. The processor performance settings can be dictated by hardware, like the BIOS. So, this might be why you can't change it. But, putting a band-aid on a serious problem with a new computer is not the correct answer.

Comment: By the way, some of these newer Dells do run very hot and the fans run alot. Especially the Intel i7. It may be perfectly normal, it's just the way it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a hardware limitation. Windows has feature to cap the max CPU in different power modes, but not all computers support it on hardware level.

In some cases this can be controlled in BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the 5579. To slow the fan down keep the Bios drivers updated. I've had to do this more than once. Also go into the Bluetooth property menu and disable the checkbox where the pc controls the on/off. You should see a huge improvement after the Bios, driver and Bluetooth areas are fixed. My fan did a complete turnaround after I did this today.